# Как в Eclipse скопировать исходники из maven-репозитория в локальный проект?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Мне в своем проекте в `Eclipse` нужно использовать слегка измененные исходники из проекта, существующего в виде `maven`-репозитория. Когда я указываю нужный репозиторий в `pom.xml` в `dependencies`, он загружается в локальный репозиторий (`...\.m2\repository\com\myproject...`), включая jar-файлы с исходниками, и исходники доступны для просмотра в `eclipse`. Как теперь эти исходники скопировать в папку внутри проекта, как обычные `java`-файлы? Когда я выполняю код

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>src-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <!-- use copy-dependencies instead if you don't want to explode the sources -->
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>sources</classifier>
          <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/sources</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

кoторый приведен в качестве примера на https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/using-dependencies-sources.html, я получаю в локальной папке файлы `.class`, а не исходники.

Comment: А что в консоль пишет на lifecycle фазе _package_?

Comment: @Tachkin что всё окей. 
`[INFO] Unpacking ...  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS`